# Ist »Ich bin heim« richtig?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Laut dem [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heim) bedeutet »heim«

> wieder nach Hause, in die Heimat zurück

Demnach sollte man das Folgende sagen können:

> (a) Ich bin heim.

Aber ich höre viel mehr von

> (b) Ich bin daheim.

Ist (a) richtig, und wird es verwendet?

(Diese Frage ist zum Teil von [dieser](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24124/at-home-daheim-zuhause-or-zu-hause) inspiriert.)

Comment: *Ich bin heim* gibt es in der Umgangssprache. Es bedeutet da allerdings nicht "ich bin daheim", sondern ist als Perfekt zu verstehen: "ich bin heim (vervollständige in Gedanken: gegangen)". Beispiel: "Bist du noch auf der Party geblieben, nachdem ich gegangen war?" - "Nein, ich bin dann auch heim."

Comment: @Chris: Man könnte hier auch argumentieren, dass hier "bin" als Bewegungsverb verwendet wird, ähnlich wie das manchmal bei "müssen" der Fall ist: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22622/why-isnt-gehen-in-the-sentence/22628#22628 allerdings funktioniert das bei "sein" und dessen Konjugationen nur in der Vergangenheit.

Comment: @chirlu: Naja, so wie ich es verstanden habe, wollte boaten wissen, ob man "ich bin heim" im Sinne von "ich bin daheim" verwenden kann. Darauf geben die beiden Poster unten die richtige Antwort: Nein. Mein Einwand, dass es "ich bin heim" in einem anderen Kontext doch geben kann, ist meines Erachtens keine eigene Antwort wert. Em1 oder HubertSchölnast könnten höchstens eine kleine Ergänzung in ihrer Antwort aufnehmen.

Comment: @Chris: Ich habe jetzt selbst eine Antwort geschrieben.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nein, das kann man nicht sagen. Dafür müsste die Definition wie folgt lauten:

> (wieder) zu Hause, in der Heimat (zurück)

Lässt du den Teil, den ich in Klammern gesetzt habe, weg, findest du die Duden-Definition für *[daheim](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/daheim)*.

Daher sagt man:

> Ich bin daheim.
>   <s>Ich bin heim.</s>

*Heim* verwendet man entsprechend, wenn das Zuhause das Ziel ist:

> Ich gehe heim[=nach Hause].

Answer (score 9):

*Ich bin heim* gibt es in der süddeutschen Umgangssprache, es bedeutet aber etwas anderes, und zwar *Ich bin nach Hause gegangen (gefahren, geflogen usw.)*. Im Gegensatz dazu bedeutet *Ich bin daheim* das Gleiche wie *Ich befinde mich zu Hause*.

---

*Daheim* ist eine **Ortsangabe** und vor allem im Süden verbreitet; weiter im Norden entspricht dem *zu Hause*:

> Ich bin seit gestern wieder daheim. Ich bin seit gestern wieder zu Hause.

*Heim* ist dagegen eine **Richtungsangabe**, entsprechend *nach Hause*, und steht daher normalerweise mit einem Verb der Bewegung:

> Wir fahren morgen heim. Wir fahren morgen nach Hause.

In vielen Fällen kann man aber auch ein anderes Verb, vor allem ein Modalverb, mit *heim* verbinden. Die Bewegung (*gehen*, *fahren* usw.) versteht sich dann von selbst. Mit *nach Hause* oder anderen Richtungsangaben funktioniert das genauso:

> Wir müssen dringend heim. Wir müssen dringend nach Hause.
> Wir müssen dringend zum Supermarkt.
>
> Willst du etwa schon heim? Willst du etwa schon nach Hause?
>
> Ich mag jetzt noch nicht heim. Ich mag jetzt noch nicht nach Hause.

Umgangssprachlich kann man auch *sein* in dieser Weise mit einer Richtungsangabe verwenden, auch hier denkt man sich eine Bewegung hinzu:

> Die Ausstellung hat mir nicht gefallen, ich bin bald wieder heim. Die Ausstellung hat mir nicht gefallen, ich bin bald wieder nach Hause.
> Er ist sofort zur Polizei, als er davon gehört hat.

Das ist die Konstruktion aus deiner Frage.

Answer (score 4):

### Nein

»Ich bin heim« ist nicht richtig.

Das Wort »heim« wird wie eine Richtung verwendet, nach der man mit »wohin« fragen kann:

<*Subjekt*> <*Bewegungs-Verb*> <*Richtung*>.

> Wir gehen vorwärts. (Wohin gehen wir?)
>   Jango reitet nach Westen. (Wohin reitet Jango?)
>   Mario rudert zurück. (Wohin rudert Mario?)
>   **Ich gehe heim.** (Wohin gehe ich?)

Auch die in der Frage zitierten Duden-Erklärungen sind Richtungen, keine Orte:

> Ich gehe **(wieder) nach Hause.** (Wohin gehe ich?)
>   Ich gehe **in die Heimat (zurück).** (Wohin gehe ich?)

---

Hingegen hat »daheim« die Bedeutung eines Ortes, den man mit »wo« erfragen kann:

<*Subjekt*> <*Zustands-Verb*> <*Ort*>.

> Wir liegen vorne. (Wo liegen wir?)
>   Jango wohnt im Westen. (Wo wohnt Jango?)
>   Mario steht hinten. (Wo steht Mario?)
>   **Ich bin daheim.** (Wo bin ich?)

Ebenfalls sind Orte:

- »**zu** Hause« (im Gegensatz zu »***nach*** Hause«)
- »in **der** Heimat« (im Gegensatz zu »*in **die** Heimat*«)

> Ich bin **zu Hause.** (Wo bin ich?)
>   Ich bin **in der Heimat**. (Wo bin ich?)

---

Erklärung zu *in d. Heimat*:

in + Dativ = Ort (wo?):

> männlich: in dem Ort (im Ort)
>   weiblich: in der Stadt, **in der Heimat**
>   sächlich: in dem Land (im Land)

in + Akkusativ = Richtung (wohin?):

> männlich: in den Ort
>   weiblich: in die Stadt, **in die Heimat**
>   sächlich: in das Land